Gamepad doesn't work over Remote Desktop Windows 10
My home computer is much more powerful than my laptop, so to play games elsewhere I'm using a remote desktop connection. The problem is, when I connect a gamepad (Xbox One controller over USB), The host computer just won't recognize it. When opening the Local Resources tab of the mstsc window, the controller is there to be redirected through RemoteFX, but when I press the home button, the Xbox game bar GUI for my client system appears, which leads me to believe it's not being redirected. I would use the RDP gamepad solution on github, but it only works with one controller and I plan to mostly use this solution to play local multiplayer with friends, else I would just use my computer at home. I've already enabled all the requisite local group policies and I'm just not sure what else to try.

Tried steam remote control? If games are on steam, you wont need RDP at all. Or your desire is strict gamepad+RDP to play any other "non-steam" games?

Yeah, I mostly want to play non steam games

Tried adding "non-steam" game to steam?

Can you add an emulator to steam?

Yes, emulators, photoshop, paint,...any exe.
